# iOS 14 Widgets with greater configuration capabilities

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I want to add more advanced configuration options to my iOS 14 Widgets. This is what I've been working with:

```
struct WidgetConfig {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let backgroundColor: Color?
    let backgroundImage: Data?
    let fontColor: Color
    let fontStyle: Font.Design
    let accentColor: Color
}
```

The user can create Configurations in the App.

I experimented with storing the Configurations in CoreData, but fetching them in the IntentHandler is very slow and unreliable. Widgets often just render black.

What would be a better strategy to implement this?

Comment: What about using a JSON encoder and saving them in a JSON file or User Defaults?

Answer (score 0):

The official way to customize Widgets is using a Siri intent file. This enables the options you see when long pressing a widget and choosing edit (the widget flips around).

> To make the most relevant information easily accessible to users,
> widgets can provide customizable properties. For example, users can
> select a specific stock for a stock quote widget, or enter a tracking
> number for a package delivery widget. Widgets define customizable
> properties by using *custom intent definitions*, the same mechanism
> that Siri Suggestions and Siri Shortcuts use for customizing those
> interactions.   To add configurable properties to your widget:
>
> 1. Add a custom intent definition that defines the configurable properties to your Xcode project.
> 2. Use an `IntentTimelineProvider` in your widget to incorporate the user’s choices into your timeline entries.
> 3. If the properties rely on dynamic data, implement an Intents extension.

– From Apple’s Article: [Making a Configurable Widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget)

There is also a detailed WWDC session on that topic I can recommend: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10194